# How can I grant a user limited permissions in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want my student assistant to be able to use SQL Server Management Studio to run basic queries to test them before using them in our application. I want her to be able to select from tables, but not to insert, delete, or truncate or anything that would otherwise affect our data.

Does anyone know how I might achieve this?

Comment: Using GRANT. Any SQL documentation has the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use DatabaseCatalogue
go    
exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, StudentAssistantsUsername 
go
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188629(v=sql.90).aspx